# Freeing space at the filesystem root in Ubuntu 18

Tags: disk-usage, disk-management

I recently installed ubuntu 18 in my laptop with

```
Filesystem Partition 5
11 GB Ext4
/dev/sda5
Mounted at Filesystem Root

Filesystem Partition 6: home
487 GB Ext4
/dev/sda6
Mounted at /home
```

I installed a couple of programs and the 11 GB partition got full, and I started to suffer some crashing form my pc. I run some commands in recovery mode, delete some folders and I'm at 7GB.

One of the more heavy folders is usr with

```
2,3G    /usr/lib
1,2G    /usr/share
276M    /usr/local
272M    /usr/src
192M    /usr/bin
71M     /usr/include
16M     /usr/sbin
684K    /usr/games
```

One of my questions is what is safe to delete here?

Also, this size was the recommended, is it too small? How do people do it, installing new programs else were?

Comment: Recommended by whom?

Comment: Ubuntu documentation states 25GB (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for 18.04.  The size you gave is fine if you don't add extra software, and will re-install (and not upgrade) to your next version, remember to clean/remove semi-regularly...  The same document gives a number of variations, eg. 1.5gb if you're using text only (no gui, no gui software) - but yes I think 11gb is too small for average/normal use.